# Handling exceptions in an xUnit test constructor and aborting tests

Tags: unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, xunit

I'm using an xUnit test constructor / dispose to manage the [shared context](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context) before a series of Selenium Tests.

The constructor does various steps such as create the WebDriver, navigate to the site under test, etc. The dispose does some clear up operations (logging, quits WebDriver).

It's not unusual for the setup steps to sporadically fail (i.e. WebDriver can't connect to the site). In that scenario a WebDriver exception is thrown and there's no point actually executing the Test (since the preconditions won't be met).

What's the preferred strategy for handling this and ensuring that the tests don't bother trying to run, and that any clean up steps are executed (so I don't end up with lots of unclosed Chrome instances).

If an exception is thrown during a Test that's fine, it registers a failure and the dispose is called after. It's specifically the situation where the test isn't setup correctly I want to streamline / make more robust.

In JUnit I would have done something like an Assume as the first step of each test.

Answer (score 0):

With current knowledge I think the best way to do it would be to use fixtures for "prerequisite selenium code" and the WebDriver Factory.

Here's a short video that i found helpful and to the point about managing shared test context: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Wp8en1I9oQ

What i did when i ran into this a while back is ugly but it does the job as well..
For context, i setup my WebDriver in a "TestBase" class which also contains a Dispose() for the driver and i extend it with my test class.

In the constructor of the test class i usually did some prerequisite actions in order to bring the web app to the required state for the test. This can sometime fail, as you describe, so what i did was to surround the selenium code from the constructor with a try-catch all, and in the catch block i call the Dispose() method. So if something would fail in the constructor, it still runs the Dispose().

```cs
public class MyTest : TestBase
{
  public MyTest(ITestOutputHelper output) : base(output)
  {
    try
    {
      // Selenium Prerequisite Actions
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // log the exception
      Dispose(); 
      // this would either be the Dispose() from TestBase or a local dispose which 
      // in turn also calls base.Dispose()
      throw ex;
  }
}
```

PS: i also miss JUnit and TestNG :(